# broadcastreceiver not working when app is closed

Tags: android

I declared Broadcast Receiver in Manifest file. It only work when app is opened in background.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".BlockCallReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```